# Как определить, запущен ли скрипт (cron)?

Tags: cron, php

Добрый день.

Я запускаю скрипт кроном с периодичностью в 5 минут. Можно ли определить, выполняется еще скрипт или нет?

Просто если скрипт уже выполняется, не желательно его дублем запускать..

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: [как настроить в cron выполнение просроченных задач](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/869/). Это не ответ на ваш вопрос, но по смыслу близко.

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов проверки использовать системную блокировку файла. В этом случае, даже если процесс помрет, блокировка будет снята и последующий запуск не будет залочен.

```
function lock($name) {
    $lock = sys_get_temp_dir()."/$name.lock";
    $aborted = file_exists($lock) ? filemtime($lock) : null;
    $fp = fopen($lock, 'w');

    if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {
        // заблокировать файл не удалось, значит запущена копия скрипта
        return false;
    }
    // получили блокировку файла

    // если файл уже существовал значит предыдущий запуск кто-то прибил извне
    if ($aborted) {
        error_log(sprintf("Запуск скрипта %s был завершен аварийно %s", $name, date('c', $aborted)));
    }

    // снятие блокировки по окончанию работы 
    // если этот callback, не будет выполнен, то блокировка 
    // все равно будет снята ядром, но файл останется
    register_shutdown_function(function() use ($fp, $lock) {
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
        unlink($lock);
    });

    return true;
}
```

Либо можно хранить в файле PID процесса, как предложил [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp). Различие этих подходов будет видно лишь на Windows.

Answer (score 1):

можно на время выполнения скрипта, чтобы он файлик создавал, файлик флаг - если имеется файл, то не работаем.
А при завершении крон скрипта файлик удалять.

Comment: В файлик (для надежности) можно свой PID (скрипта из крона) положить и проверять, если такой процесс запущен, то файлик актуален.

Comment: Есть нюанс, если крон сдохнет, то файл останется, а процесса не будет